# How to add an image properly?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, bitmap

If I add an Image into my XML file, it works properly. But I am wondering if I don't have to Change my Java-code to add an image?  The image has no function. It is only there to look at it. As I said  my activity works, because I can see the image in my activity. But I am wondering if I have to mention the image in my Java-Code?

Comment: If it works, no need to change it. If you are just showing an image no need to do any Java code for it, just figure out the appropriate xml and you are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to mention it in Java code, if your sole requirement is just to display the image. It's required only when you need to modify the behavior of some UI element at runtime (e.g. if you need to enable or disable a button at runtime based on certain conditions, then you need to get a reference to it and modify it in Java code). But as per your question, only adding in xml is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the reference of the image is called from your layout, and it loads correctly, you don´t have to change anything.

Comment: And if it is not loading correctly, and an OutOfMemory Error occurs?

Answer (score -1):

picasso jar i think you will need it to solve caching issue and to load pics from url without doing code by your self

it just need the imageview and it will load any image either from sd card , drawable folder or from url.
all imageview layout will be same as it is.

try it http://square.github.io/picasso/